# For Material UI, how can I know what the properties of each components are?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to learn material ui but I'm having difficulty knowing, for a given component, what are its properties that I can use when calling it? I was watching a tutorial on youtube where they use AppBar

```
<AppBar title="Enter user details" />
```

how do they know there's the property "title"? I was trying to look up in the official website: https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#props

but it never says that one of the properties is "title"

This is just one example, how can I learn all the properties for any component I want to experiment on?

Comment: `AppBar` doesn't have a `title` property, but it did back in the [0.x versions](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v0.x/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L134), so the YouTube tutorial you watched is out-of-date. Version 1.0 was significantly different from the preceding versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check API of the AppBar which you can find in this link:

https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/

AppBar only have children, classes, color, position as props.

Example: `<AppBar position="sticky"></AppBar>`

Keep in mind, those are the default props that you can use out of the box, you can always make your own component on top of AppBar so that you will have more functionally as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

MUI AppBar don't have a title prop. It was there in 0x version as @RyanCogswell mentioned. It was later removed. https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

To set the title you need to do something like this.

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
    <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
      <MenuIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
      News
    </Typography>

  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

[image]

> how can I learn all the properties for any component I want to experiment on?

It will be in the Component API documentation section in the left pane